# Meteor not loading external CSS and JS files

Tags: javascript, css, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to load my stylesheets and js files in Meteor. I have an index.html file. This is what I was doing at first:

```
<link href="assets/plugins/boostrapv3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

There were lots of stylesheet files and script files. This was working fine but if i wrote a url like: 'localhost:3000/manage-user/add', everything stopped working. I have read loads of answers where they have mentioned that I need to make a **lib** folder and in that folder, I need to make a **css** and a **js** folder, but it's not picking up my files, especially my 'style.css' file which overrides styles of bootstrap and all.

Comment: Showing your project folders and files structure would surely help in people understanding your situation.

Answer (score 0):

assets folder should be inside the /public folder, then try add the / to the begining of the href value.

```
<link href="/assets/plugins/boostrapv3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: They are already placed in the 'public' folder. This method works fine, but I need a way to include them automatically. Everyone has suggested that if I put my css files in 'client/lib/css' folder, meteor is going to automatically include them but that's not happening

Answer (score 0):

URL can be absolute and relative.

Absolute should starts from protocol value(http://, https://, ftp:// etc) and then domain name, port, path and query part.
Relative can be started either from slash or any other character.

If URL is started from slash it's assumed its value is relative to domain's root.

If URL is started from any other character it's assumed it's value is relative to current URL(or value in  tag).

Anyway value `localhost:3000/manage-user/add` means for browser: 
"take current page's URL and append this value to its end". 
So your files are tried to be fetched from something like `http://localhost:3000/localhost:3000/manage-user/add`

Comment: yes, this is exactly the issue. If I only use direct urls without appending anything, then everything works fine but I need proper urls. That's why I am trying to move files to 'client/lib/css' and 'client/lib/js' folders so they get included automatically, but even that's not happening

Answer (score 0):

**To properly add your styles.css and/or your templates/components to your app, you must register/add them as an import path to the body.js.**

**CSS**

1. Go to your body.js.
2. Add `import '/imports/ui/stylesheets/styles.css'` (copy/paste this line)

**JS** - Templates/pages

1. Go to your body.js in your layouts folder.
2. Add `import '/imports/ui/pages/[yourDirName]/[yourFileName].js';` (copy/paste this line)

**BONUS Content!**

**JS** - Components to import into your html templates (optional)

1. Go to your pages folder.
2. Select the proper directory.
3. Select the js file that is importing your html template file.
4. Import the component to the js file.
5. import `'../../components/[yourDirName]/[yourFileName].js;`

**Example** `import '../../components/hello/hello.js';`